# Calculating a column for all rows in one data frame from information in two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have working, but I imagine not efficient or correctly written pandas/python code below to try to calculate a column value for all rows in a data frame using information from that data frame plus another data frame where I am performing a join-like operation on a similar column from each data frame.  In df1 below, common_key_1 is a string whereas in df2 below, common_key_2 is a Series of strings which I would want to individually match against (an any condition).

So what I am trying to do is to have the find operation work on each string in a Series as opposed to a single string like I have below.  What is the more proper way which allows me to avoid the for loop?

```
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    key_in_df1 = predictions_df[common_key_1][i]
    matching_df = df2.loc[df2[common_key_2].apply(lambda x: any((i for i in x if i.find(key_in_df1) >= 0)))]
    val = matching_df[value_column].sum()
    number_rows = len(matching_df)
    overall_value = 0 if number_rows == 0 else val * (2.0 / 3.0) / number_rows
    df1.loc[i,(column_to_set)] = overall_value
```

Comment: Can you include some samples of your dataframes `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: Well df1 has 2 columns, the common_key_1 (which is a string) and the column_to set (which is a float in the range [-2/3,2/3]).  So initially an example df1 row is 'ABC1' and 0.  The df2 has 3 columns: a df specific id (string), value_column (numeric either -1, 0 or 1), and common_key_2 (Series of strings) like {'ABC1', 'ABC2', 'ABC3}.  In this case, my sample df1 row has its common key in df2 sample row's column so I would use that value_column to calculate column_to_set in df1.

Comment: it seems easier for you to just include a sample of your data than to type it all out...

Comment: I'd prefer to not include my actual data.  Values and column names have been changed.

Comment: I am thinking that I would have to explode my data in df2.  That is transform the data frame such that each row contained a single string (say 'ABC'3).  My original working code is oh so slow.